# Queuing up videos for live stream

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, streaming

Would first like to tell that am new to streaming and ffmpeg.

Would try to explain scenario as much as possible.

A web service is intended to receive chunks of video from a user. those chunks need to be simultaneously sent to the web for live streaming for a seamless viewing.

So the videos need to be queued up for streaming to the web so that it looks like a long single video. and the strict requirement is not to make any temp file on disk.

Did read something about pipes but am completely alien to that concept as well.

Kindly tell how / whether this can be achieved from FFMPEG or any other free tool  .

Language used is PHP . The received videos also need to be saved to disk in parallel for new users to see from start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an RTMP publisher that reads a flv/mpeg/avi/mov file (etc) and then connects to Red5, Wowza, or Flash Media Server.

You don't need tempfiles, just retrieve the video files from the user (in some manner) and then write a php scripts that uses ffmpeg to send them to the streaming server:

ffmpeg -i /home/video.avi -re -acodec libfaac - vcodec libx264 -vpre default -f flv rtmp://serverip/app/streamName